# IF statement for last value in LookupSet expression

Tags: arrays, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have an expression to get the last date value but I get '#Error' if there is no date entered. (`IF` part returns #Error because no date has been entered - the `Else` part returns a date).  Here is the expression:

`IIF(LookupSet(Fields!Denial_ID.Value,Fields!Denial_ID.Value,Fields!Appeal_Date_Entered.Value,"DataSet2").Length() =0, "", LookupSet(Fields!Denial_ID.Value, Fields!Denial_ID.Value, Fields!Appeal_Date_Entered.Value, "DataSet2")(LookupSet(Fields!Denial_ID.Value, Fields!Denial_ID.Value, Fields!Appeal_Date_Entered.Value, "DataSet2").Length() -1))`

Comment: Please specify the language you're asking in tags and format the expression so that it is readable. I can't even see any `Else` in this and can't really help you formatting this properly because the syntax doesn't seem to have any sense: it looks like you have some extra/missing parentheses in it

Comment: I'm sorry - I'm very new to writing expressions.  This is an expression that I am using in Report Builder.  The expression is working, and will return the a date if one has been entered, but if the date is not entered, I get #Error

Comment: So what's the language? Is this from Excel? Are you talking about Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder? Please describe your environment.

Comment: Yes, Microsoft Report Builder v3.0

Comment: Are there any report writers that could assist?  I have seen posts stating this a known issue with IF statements.  What is the correct the syntax to not get '#Error' when the date has not been entered?

Answer (score 0):

I'm definitely not a report writer, but there's some strange stuff in your expression which make me expect it not to work. Below is a formatted version of it (it's easier to analyse it, although I have no idea of whitespace syntax in MRB):

```
IIF(
  LookupSet(Fields!Denial_ID.Value,
    Fields!Denial_ID.Value,
    Fields!Appeal_Date_Entered.Value,"DataSet2").Length() =0,
  "",
  LookupSet(Fields!Denial_ID.Value,
    Fields!Denial_ID.Value,
    Fields!Appeal_Date_Entered.Value, "DataSet2")
  (LookupSet(Fields!Denial_ID.Value,
    Fields!Denial_ID.Value,
    Fields!Appeal_Date_Entered.Value,
    "DataSet2").Length() -1)
)
```

According to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expression-examples-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017#DecisionFunctions), the `IIF` syntax is the following:

```
=IIF(condition, valueIfTrue, valueIfFalse)
```

but your expression looks like this:

```
IIF(condition, valueIfTrue, valueIfFalse (someOtherStuff))
```

so you should describe what you expect to get from that expression and change it to accord the standart syntax (see also examples on the referenced page).

Comment: The Appeal Date Value I am trying to display may have 0  to 3 values and I am trying to get the last value entered.  The expression is able to retrieve that value successfully if a date has been entered.  However, when no date has been entered, that is when I get #Error.  Reading through other posts, I believe that when using IIF, because the first result has no value, it returns the error.  I have seem some posts suggesting the use of MID, Split, JOIN within the expression, but I can't seem to get the syntax correct.